# How to separate and get geographic area info from planetosm

Tags: openstreetmap, osgeo

I have planetosm data file which is nearly 18GB now i need to seperate and get only my country details. Is there any way to seperate that data from osm file? I'm using OSGEO 6.05

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the WeoGeo Market where you can download only specific layers of the planetosm and limit the geographic area you obtain. http://market.weogeo.com - free access and OSM is free too there. Just create an account.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the daily snapshots from http://download.geofabrik.de ?

Comment: I'm looking the latest update of SriLanka. geofabrik don't have it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) - I use something like (but there are [other options](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_Usage)):

> osmosis --read-xml enableDateParsing=no file=..\Data\OSM\great-britain-latest.osm --bounding-box top=51
>   .126 bottom=50.729 left=-0.03 right=0.7 --write-xml file=new.osm

Comment: I do not understand the option that you have mentioned in your command \Data\OSM\great-britain-latest.osm. I am trying to download data for Sri Lanka. Lats and Longs respectively are 78.87634 10.28249 , 83.05115 5.79090. Please can you show the method to download the data.

Comment: you would need to insert your own file names in the example I gave